# JDBC or Copy INTO

Tags: talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help in determining a way to load data from different sources to snowflake. To extract the data we have etl,talend, tool. Now the question is , should we load data to snowflake through JDBC driver of snowflake and treat snowflake as target in etl pipeline or should we create a file first in s3 ,create stage of s3 in snwoflake , and run copy into command to load the data from s3 ? We will have many jobs ,

What is the best way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 and copy into is definitely a better call - both in terms of time and final data structure. When doing true bulk operations Snowflake will be able to optimize how the data is stored and as a result your queries ran on the loaded data will perform better.

Comment: Thank you , Can you pls provide more details why s3 /copy into is best compare to jdbc ? What are the best practices and how Other companies r using it ?

Comment: Snowflake internal partitions are immutable - so they are created and from that moment the only thing that can happen is a record being deleted from them. So JDBC from Snowflake point of view is (most likely) going to perform a ton of single-row inserts, causing a separate partition to be created for each of those rows significantly increasing the IO ops needed to read the data. On the other hand COPY will group the data into partitions properly, allowing both filtering (and related optimization) and simply less IOPS to grab the needed data

Comment: I was doing research and came accross to a video where it says native JDBC connection of Talend/Informatica converts the load process as copy into cmd , is that true ? I know tDBOutputBulkExec component creates copy into command but it requires , file as a input.

Comment: no idea, you'd have to check that with the informatica/talend guys